# Axios is sending OPTIONS instead of POST to Django

Tags: django, vue.js, axios

I'm using Django Rest Framework with a front-end in Vue. I'm using axios to make POST requests to Django, but the Django server is receiving OPTIONS requests, as you can see in the server log.

```
"OPTIONS /save/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 59396)
```

The problem doesn't appear to be in the server, since CORS is configured correctly and I can send a POST request with Postman. Here's the javascript code

```
async save() {
  let data = {
    "name": this.name,
    "title": this.title,
  }
  let config = {
    header : {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
  }   
  response = await axios.post(
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/save/',
    data,
    config
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser will always send an `OPTIONS` request when the back end is on a different domain. It might be worth troubleshooting your CORS config to ensure it is successfully processing the `OPTIONS` request and returning the right response. Only once the `OPTIONS` request returns `200` will the browser send your `POST` request. See this excellent article on CORS for more detail: https://codeburst.io/cors-story-of-requesting-twice-85219da7172d